# How could I replicate the opposite of this lerping function?

Tags: java, math

In the lerping function below, it will slow down a camera which is following a moving object, and as the moving object slows down or stops the camera catches up to it. I need the opposite. I need the camera to move ahead of the moving object and slow down back to the object when the object slows/stops. I can't seem to make it work. Any ideas?

```
//this is the opposite of what I want.
float lerp = 0.1f;
Vector3 position = this.getCamera().position;
position.x += (Obj.x - position.x) * lerp;
position.y += (Obj.y - position.y) * lerp;
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the -position.(x,y) to +position(x,y)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just increase to `110%` instead of decreasing to `10%`

```
float lerp = 1.1f;
position.x += (Obj.x + position.x) * lerp;
position.y += (Obj.y + position.y) * lerp;
```

Example:

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    double position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        position = (position + 10) * 1.1;
        System.out.println("position = " + position);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I would have thought except that it doesn't work. It acts as if it were set to 0. Probably to to acceleration of the object cancelling it out.

Comment: I assumed you would add the position as well instead of subtracting it